# Clarification - AWS ECS services with auto scaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Below is the skeleton, how I start an AWS ECS Service on EC2

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "engine" {
  image_id      = "ami-05339d597592d45cf" # Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux 2 (AL2) x86_64 AMI

  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]
  iam_instance_profile {
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg" {
  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.engine[each.key].id
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "provider" {
  auto_scaling_group_provider {
    auto_scaling_group_arn = aws_autoscaling_group.asg[each.key].arn

    managed_scaling {
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster_capacity_providers" "providers" {
  cluster_name       = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name
  capacity_providers = [for provider in aws_ecs_capacity_provider.provider : provider.name]
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = var.module_name
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  capacity_provider_strategy {
    capacity_provider = var.capacity_providers[each.value.instance_type].name
  }
  network_configuration {
  }
}
```

**Factoids**

As I understand my situation:

1. I wanted to host a service (1 task of the service) on 1 EC2 that is managed by the Auto Scaling group. Based on my understanding, it allocates all resources on the particular EC2, so no other service / task can be accommodated on the given instance
2. The Auto Scaling Group is tighten into the cluster's capacity provider, but based on the information I have found on the internet, 1 Auto Scaling Group is for manage instances for 1 service
3. Each ECS Cluster has only 6 registered Capacity providers
4. I have tried to deploy +1 service with a capacity provider already in used (its desired capacity was set to 1, max capacity 10), and the new service couldn't start, because the capacity provider haven't started a new instance for the new service

**The problem**

I need multiple services in the same cluster, but as I tried to conclude above, each service needs own capacity provider (because it needs own Auto Scaling Group), but this number is limited to 6

Can somebody clarify my, how can I host multiple services in the same ECS Cluster and avoid the Capacity provider limit?

**Update**

This is the real auto scalig group and capacity provider Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg" {
  for_each = local.instance_types

  name                = "${var.module_name}-${each.key}"
  vpc_zone_identifier = [var.subnet_id]

  desired_capacity          = 1
  min_size                  = 0
  max_size                  = 10
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  health_check_type         = "EC2"

  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.engine[each.key].id
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "provider" {
  for_each = local.instance_types

  name = "${var.module_name}-${replace(each.key, ".", "_")}"
  auto_scaling_group_provider {
    auto_scaling_group_arn = aws_autoscaling_group.asg[each.key].arn

    managed_scaling {
      status                    = "ENABLED"
      target_capacity           = 100
      minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
      maximum_scaling_step_size = 100
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  for_each = var.accounts

  name                               = "${var.module_name}-${each.key}"
  cluster                            = var.cluster_id
  task_definition                    = aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition[each.key].arn
  desired_count                      = 1
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 100
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 0

  capacity_provider_strategy {
    weight            = 1
    capacity_provider = var.capacity_providers[each.value.instance_type].name
  }
  network_configuration {
    subnets         = [var.subnet_id]
    security_groups = [var.security_group_id]
  }

  tags = var.tags
}
```

What I have experienced, if I have two services from 2 different task definition, the second service cannot start, because not enough capacity on the EC2 instance used be the first service.

Moreover, checking the EC2 instances, I have experienced, that only 1 instance is running

Answer (score 0):

> The Auto Scaling Group is tighten into the cluster's capacity provider, but based on the information I have found on the internet, 1 Auto Scaling Group is for manage instances for 1 service

This is incorrect. The capacity provider is for the entire ECS cluster, not for a specific service running in that cluster.

> I need multiple services in the same cluster, but as I tried to conclude above, each service needs own capacity provider (because it needs own Auto Scaling Group)

Again, this is incorrect. One capacity provider, with one auto-scaling group, is enough for the entire cluster regardless of how many services you are running in that cluster.

Comment: I have updated my original post. In that case, maybe the auto-scaling won't work,because I cannot start 2 service

Comment: You need to explain what is actually  happening. When you try to deploy the second service, do you see the desired count on the auto-scaling group change? What is the status of the second service after it fails to deploy? Is there an error in the ECS log at any point, or does it just say the service is in "pending" state forever?